# How to find the size of a generic singly-linked list in java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I am having trouble finding out the size of a generic singly-linked list in java. Here is my code (below I will explain how I tried to find it out and what difficulties I encountered):

```
class List<T> {
/**
 * An immutable singly-linked list.
 * @param <T> the type of the list elements
 */
T head;
List<T> tail;

List(T head, List<T> tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
}

/** Generic helper function for list creation. You DO NOT NEED to call this function. */
static <U> List<U> node(U head, List<U> tail) {
    return new List<U>(head, tail);
}


/* Getters and Setters for the head and the tail; */
public List<T> getTail() {
    return tail;
}

public void setTail(List<T> tail) {
    this.tail = tail;
}

public T getHead() {
    return head;
}

public void setHead(T head) {
    this.head = head;
}
```

I tried to find out the size like this:
loop through the elements of the linked list, beninning with the first element, until the "next" pointer shows `null`. increment the helper variable `size`.
Code:

```
    public int size(){
    int size = 0;

    T temp = head;
    while (temp.getTail() != null) {
        temp = temp.getTail();
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

The problem is `temp.getTail()`. Eclipse is asking in this specific case to cast the variable `temp` to `List<T>`. But this makes for me no sense, hence `List<T>` should be just like a "next" pointer to the next element of the list.

Could somebody please be so kind and explin what I'm doing wrong and how I could solve this. I am really trying to understand generics (I also read a lot about generics but still can't seem to figure out how to handle this kind of situation).

I will use this list in my test class:

```
        List<Integer> coins = List.node(1, List.node(2, List.node(5,  List.node(10,
            List.node(20, List.node(50, List.node(100,  List.node(200, null))))))));
```

I will recursively calculate the number of possible coin combinations (the values 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 and 200) given an EURO amount.

Comment: Why the type of `tail` is `List<T>`? Also, `getTemp()` method is defined in `List<T>`, and you are trying to invoke it from `T` type variable. That is not going to work.

Comment: @RohitJain this is a class assignment. The attributes of the class `List<T>` were given to us. I'm also trying to figure out, why `tail` is of type `List<T>` and not only `T`. My guess is, that `tail` some kind of "next" pointer is, that shows to the next element of the list. How can I iterate through the elements of the list in this case in order to find out the size? This is my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
int size = 1;

List<T> temp = this;

while (temp.getTail() != null) {
    temp = temp.getTail();
    size++;
}
```

`T` does not have a tail, a `List<T>` does however, which is what your temp should be.

ie suppose it is a `List<Integer>` then your Code would look like:

```
Integer temp = head;
while (temp.getTail() != null) {
    temp = temp.getTail(); 
    size++;
}
```

`temp` is an `Integer` and the tail will be a `List<Integer>`, so you can't assign a lit of integers to an `Integer`.

Comment: You've got an off-by-one error.  But other than that it's fine (same as my iterative), so have an upvote!

Comment: @vandale thank you very much for the fast response. I have a question though. Why start the incrementation of count from 1 and not from 0? As far as I know, The first element of the list hast the index 0.

Comment: @user3185735 assume you have a list. this means that the list will have at least one element, so you start at 1. Then each additional element add 1 more to that. Think of it like an array: it last element will be at `length-1` but is `length` long

Comment: @vandale that makes perfectly sense for me now :) thank you very much for the help. 
You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke `getTail()` from a `T` when it's defined in `List<T>`.

An iterative solution that will work is:

```
public int size(){
    int size = 1;

    List<T> temp = this;
    while (temp.getTail() != null) {
        temp = temp.getTail();
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Though it might not be advisable in Java, the recursive solution is perhaps more in keeping with your recursive data structure:

```
public int size() {
    if (getTail() == null)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + getTail().size();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. This and @vandale response has sealed the deal :). Just one question though... why do we need the `T head` in this case, since we don't store data in this attribute? Any oppinions on this?

Comment: The `head` is the data.  If you want for instance to print the list, you would recurse or iterate through and print the `head` field in each entry.

Comment: thank you very much :) you helped me solve my next issue, get the data from a specific index of the list.